# Adding span element to show error messages

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using a directive on a field to prevent the user from entering **html** tags as well as **javascript events**, but I'm facing couple issues:

**a)** I want to be able to **show an error message** as soon as the user enters **html** tags or **javascript** events.

**b)** Instead of alerting the error messages I want to **show an error message** inside of an **span tag** (maybe adding an element).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my working code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-automation-n66jia?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
@HostListener('keyup',['$event'])
   onkeyup(event:any){

   if (this.control.control.value.match(/<script.*?>.+<\/script>/i)) {
       alert('HTML script tags are not allowed.');
       }
   else if(this.control.control.value.match(/<\/?\w+ +[^>]*on[a-z]+=["'].+["'][^>]*>/gi)){
    alert('HTML event handlers are not allowed.');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add custom components for your extra spans. Adding dom elements requires in good angular practice to use a structural directive: *directive

This structural directive doesn't reference directly the element in which you apply it, rather it works as a wrapper, so you need to use the native element to get the reference to the next sibling.

Passing wether or not the components should show is done via component instance, angular however sugests that dynamic components should only communicate via a service, which you could do. but the changes to your live example work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-automation-84vitx

You should of course declare the components in the .module as well as declare the custom error components as entry components so they can be loaded dynamicaly.

```
@Component({template:`<span *ngIf="show">No script tags please</span>`})
export class NoScriptComponent{
  public show = false;
};
@Component({template:`<span *ngIf="show">No html tags please</span>`})
export class NoHtmlComponent{
  public show = false;
};
@Directive({
  selector: '[customTextField]'
})
export class CustomDropDownDirective {
 const htmlError;
 const jsError;
  @Output() updateProperty: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>, private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver, private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.template)
    const next = this.template.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;

      next.onkeyup = this.onkeyup.bind(this);
      const cmpJsFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(NoScriptComponent);
      this.jsError = this.vcr.createComponent(cmpJsFactory)
      const cmpHtmlFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(NoHtmlComponent);
      this.htmlError = this.vcr.createComponent(cmpHtmlFactory)

  }

    onkeyup(event:any){
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value.match(/<script.*?>.+<\/script>/i)) {
      this.jsError.instance.show=true;


        }
    else if(value.match(/<\/?\w+ +[^>]*on[a-z]+=["'].+["'][^>]*>/gi)){
      this.htmlError.instance.show=true;
    } else {
            this.jsError.instance.show= false;
            this.htmlError.instance.show= false;

    }
  }
```

Comment: Allright - got the link fixed. try it now. I think the regex for the html tags is not good though. Try the <script> tags

Comment: Btw, I couldn't delete cuz I can only comment on my own posts, and I was communicating with you.

Comment: your live demo doesn't seem to work or check for either html tags or script tags. Did you test it?

Comment: It DOES work.... Consider your regular expression: You need <script>a</script> if script is empty it doesn't work. Your html regex I didn't debug.

Comment: any ideas on how to not allow html tags?

Comment: I've changed the example to reflect: /<.*>/g (anything between < > will trigger the component NoHtmlComponent)

Comment: One quick question. I also want to invalidate the form when getting those error messages so this will stop the user from sending data to the service. Is your answer also invalidating the form?

Comment: No, as far as I understand it, for that you need to create a validator directive and import tokens to interact with NgForm, and the errors would be displayed with inline templates. It wouldn't satisfy your request of having spans... (or arbitrary components emanating out of the directive alone). but I could figure out a way of doing it. This stuff also interests me for my work. Not today though. This question has taken me to hell and back.

Comment: Bro I think I can figure out setting the form as invalid :). I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Neat :) now I can comment on other people's stuff. Regarding form validity: you could of course replicate the logic used in this thing in a separate validator. The beauty of all this work is to create forms that do all this just by adding a simple keyword... it's like magic efficient for us dev monkeys who are doing forms.